# CoreUI Vue template integration with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have downloaded "CoreUI Free Vue Bootstrap Admin Template" from GitHub. Link is : https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template/. I want to use this theme with my Laravel backend.

I don't want to use blade template in laravel rather I want to use this CoreUI template for my frontend. So precisely, I want to use laravel and this theme separately, one works for frontend another for backend. How can I do this?

1. Should I paste the CoreUI theme file in laravel public folder?
2. Or can I run this CoreUI theme separately connecting the theme with my Laravel backend? I've tried this way. But for my case, I doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Coding is more like a series of  experiment activity ,you can  try it your own and show   us the problem you have confronted.

Comment: You'll put your CoreUI HTML **into** Blade templates, which are fundamentally just HTML (and PHP/Blade instructions that *generate* HTML).

Answer (score 1):

Please check our official Laravel integration - https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-laravel-admin-template/